# Button Click in one viewController get to know in another ViewController

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I have two UIviewControllers in storyboad.
 Eg:UIViewControler-A and UIViewController-B.

I have a Boolean variable in the ViewController A and its default value is NO.

There is a close button in the UIViewContoller B,( to dismiss the view controller).

My question is when I click the close button in the viewContoller B, The boolean Value of ViewContoller A should become YES. 
Please help.

Comment: show the code of how you dismiss the view controller and how you modify the bool value.

Answer (score 2):

You could either set view controller A as a delegate of view controller B and create/call a delegate method when the button in view controller B is tapped, or you could post a notification when the button in view controller B is tapped and add an observer in view controller A that calls a method to update your boolean in view controller A.

Comment: Thanks for the answer

Comment: You're welcome!  One note on solution B...if you do go down that path, don't forget to remove the notification observer in controller A when it deallocates..otherwise it will continue to observer the notification and the app will crash when it tries to call your update bool method on the deallocated controller..